# SQl statement of DELETE query giving error

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

Hey guys i have data in my "store_ip" table where i am storing the email of user and his ip address. So once the user clicks on logout button i need to delete that row which is related to that user from "store_ip", so what i did was

```
app.post("/user_logout",  function (req, res) {
  var postData = req.body;

 console.log(typeof(postData.email))

  connection.query(
    "DELETE FROM store_ip WHERE email = " + postData.email,
    postData,
    function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;

      res.end(JSON.stringify({ status: 200, message: "Login Data deleted!" }));
    }
  );
});
```

the formdata has an email as is needed to be but still i am getting an error

```
   sqlMessage:
  'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
   server version for the right syntax to use near \'@gmail.com\' at line 1',
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'DELETE FROM store_ip WHERE email = ratnabh2616@gmail.com' }
```

Comment: You need to encapsulate your SQL string parameters in quotes. `"DELETE FROM store_ip WHERE email = '"+ postData.email + "'",`

Comment: @user3647971 thnks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with this line you need to add ' before your email.

```
 "DELETE FROM store_ip WHERE email = " + postData.email,
```

It should be something like

```
"DELETE FROM store_ip WHERE email = '" + postData.email+"'",
```